# Accuracy in history dictionary different from what printed on screen

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

When training a model in Keras, the accuracies printed on-screen at every epoch are different from what saved in the history object. For example (minimal test, compacted output):

```
history = model.fit(...)

Epoch 1/5
156/156 [===] - loss: 0.6325 - accuracy: 0.7700 - val_loss: 0.4330 - val_accuracy: 0.8156
Epoch 2/5
156/156 [===] - loss: 0.3855 - accuracy: 0.8538 - val_loss: 0.4692 - val_accuracy: 0.8050
Epoch 3/5
156/156 [===] - loss: 0.3918 - accuracy: 0.8427 - val_loss: 0.4666 - val_accuracy: 0.7861
Epoch 4/5
156/156 [===] - loss: 0.3820 - accuracy: 0.8461 - val_loss: 0.4101 - val_accuracy: 0.8014
Epoch 5/5
156/156 [===] - loss: 0.3927 - accuracy: 0.8492 - val_loss: 0.4092 - val_accuracy: 0.7979
```

Then (rounding like printed values for convenience):

```
>>> [round(x, 4) for x in history.history['accuracy']]
[0.8184, 0.8474, 0.8484, 0.8488, 0.8476]
>>> [round(x, 4) for x in history.history['val_accuracy']]
[0.8156, 0.805, 0.7861, 0.8014, 0.7979]
```

As you can see, while validation accuracies match printed values, training accuracies do not (tested both in Colab with GPU and local PC with CPU, using Keras 2.4.0 and TensorFlow 2.4.1).

This is a problem if you want to save data from multiple tests to a file, for example. What am I getting wrong?

**EDIT**: here is an example to reproduce the problem, slightly modified from TF MNIST quickstart. See the block right after calling `model.fit()`.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14Uogeq8wRlZlinaKLbkFr_Bl2aLzUJuy?usp=sharing

**EDIT 2**: as suggested by another user, I submitted a bug issue here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48408

Comment: Share that colab link if possible. Importantly, please provide a reproducible code.

Comment: I don't think I'm allowed to link it, at least not until it will be published. And then you would need the dataset, and wait some hours for the actual training. Maybe someone can check it it happens to them, too.

Comment: The problem you are referring sounds like a general issue. If so, you would also able to reproduce it with any dataset.

Comment: Ok I added a shared notebook to reproduce the (maybe)problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used your colab and able to reproduce your issue. Yes, this seems like a **serious bug**. I tested the code in both CPU and GPU mode with `tf 2.0, 2.1, 2.3` **without any issue**. But this issue causes in `tf 2.4` and `tf-nightly`.

I would suggest you raise a bug issue in [TensorFlow GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new?assignees=&labels=type%3Abug&template=00-bug-issue.md). And share a cross-link here and there so that others can follow the update. In the meantime, you can roll back to `tf 2.3`. However, I didn't check whether `callbacks.CSVLogger` also has some issue in the latest release, you can check that too.

Comment: Thanks, I submitted a bug as you suggested, see edit in original post.

Comment: Update: CSVLogger reports the same values as history.history, but that does not clarify which values are correct, I guess.